# printing list of xml nodes in c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I am need bit of help on getting list of xml nodes and printing them.

My code is as below:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("To44532.xml");
        XmlNode xn = doc.DocumentElement;
        foreach (XmlNode xn2 in xn)
        { Console.WriteLine(xn2); }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I am new to c# please accept my apologies in advance for asking this basic question. So I wanted full list of nodes and then printing them in output.

I ended up with this piece of code because I wanted to debug one of the other code. The idea was that I wanted to display specific nodes in winforms. I tried if statement e.g. :

```
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
        {
            if (node.Equals("DbtItm"))
            { ..... }
```

Could you please advise whats the best way to achieve it?

Comment: node cannot be equal to a string, but node name. You should do it like "DbtItm".Equals(node.Name)

Answer (score 2):

You can select XML Nodes by Name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
 <book category="cooking">
   <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
   <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
   <year>2005</year>
   <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
   <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
   <author>J K. Rowling</author>
   <year>2005</year>
   <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
   <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
   <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
   <year>2003</year>
   <price>39.95</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

For example to get only book author and  book year from as above xml.

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load("XMLFile1.xml"); 

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/bookstore/book");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            string author = xn["author"].InnerText;
            string year = xn["year"].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(author+"-"+year);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. What I wanted to achieve was done by the code below: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("To44532.xml");
            XmlNodeList xxnn = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DbtItm"); 
            foreach (XmlNode node in xxnn)
            { .... }

Comment: Code above will get list of all nodes with name ''Dbtitm'' and will store it in xmlNodeList object. and then from foreach each node ''Dbtitm'' with will be iterated.