# Display field from XML Response Data using C# Console

Tags: c#, xml

I have below xml response data. Now i need to display ProjectName and MigrationStatus using C# console Application. I am new to C# please guide me to get fied names from xml node list. I have tried below code but confuisng a lot. 
Thanks in advance

XML Response Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://URL"
    <id><<URL>></id>
    <title type="text">Projects</title>
    <updated>2020-06-07T06:24:57Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="Projects" href="Projects" />
    <entry>
        <id><<URL>>(guid'86c492af-8c63-ea11-b119-00155d6c5103')</id>
        <category term="ReportingData.Project" scheme="<<URL>>" />
        <link rel="edit" title="Project" href="Projects(guid'86c492af-8c63-ea11-b119-00155d6c5103')" />
        <title />
        <updated>2020-06-07T06:24:57Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:NOde1>BULLL</d:ProjectName>
                <d:NOde2>DOM</d:NOde2>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
 </feed>
```

Comment: You mentioned code, are you still editing the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printing list of xml nodes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864860/printing-list-of-xml-nodes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Have you tried like ANYTHING in C# so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following xml linq to parse file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement feed = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = feed.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace nsM = feed.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("m");
            XNamespace nsD = feed.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("d");

            List<Entry> entries = doc.Descendants(ns + "entry").Select(x => new Entry()
            {
                id = (string)x.Element(ns + "id"),
                title = (string)x.Element(ns + "title"),
                updated = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "updated"),
                author_name = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "name").FirstOrDefault(),
                ProjectName = (string)x.Descendants(nsD + "ProjectName").FirstOrDefault(),
                MigrationStatus = (string)x.Descendants(nsD + "MigrationStatus").FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, Entry> dict = entries
                .GroupBy(x => x.ProjectName, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Entry> entry in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Entry
    {
         public string id { get; set; }
         public string title { get; set; }
         public DateTime updated { get; set; }
         public string author_name { get; set; }
         public string ProjectName { get; set; }
         public string MigrationStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have above xml response in a varibale, i got it from ODATA URL. can you please how to do that..

Comment: You can replace FILENAME with a URL so you can download directly.  I;ll add a dictionary so you can lookup by project name.

Comment: Thanks a lot jdweng. Please let me know how to write it on Console.? 
Thanks in advance.  This is my last question..

Comment: How to you want the output?  Use Console.WriteLine();

Comment: tried(Console.WriteLine(Entry.ProjectName);) but not able to diplay project names with console.writeline();
i want to dispaly all ProjectNames from the XML Response body..