# How to output data from api with c# web application web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api, webforms

I am beginner and I want to make c#.net web form which call an API .
When I did my code there were no errors but the data was not showing,it was just a blank space. Can somebody explain to me why ? I am using xml type API . Thanks in advance ! Here is my Code:

This is one of the examples from the xml file but it has open and close tag:

`

```
<current>
<city id="2756136" name="Emmen">
<coord lon="6.91" lat="52.78"/>
<country>NL</country>
<timezone>7200</timezone>
<sun rise="2020-06-08T03:09:19" set="2020-06-08T19:53:53"/>
</city>
<temperature value="286.14" min="285.15" max="286.48" unit="kelvin"/>
<feels_like value="284.26" unit="kelvin"/>
<humidity value="87" unit="%"/>
<pressure value="1012" unit="hPa"/>
<wind>
<speed value="3.1" unit="m/s" name="Light breeze"/>
<gusts/>
<direction value="220" code="SW" name="Southwest"/>
</wind>
<clouds value="75" name="broken clouds"/>
<visibility value="10000"/>
<precipitation mode="no"/>
<weather number="803" value="broken clouds" icon="04d"/>
<lastupdate value="2020-06-08T07:08:14"/>
</current>
```

`

```
private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string city;

      city = TypeCity.Text;
      string url = string.Format("http://api...", city);

      XDocument Document = XDocument.Load(url);

      WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
      string Temperature = (string)Document.Descendants("temperature.value").FirstOrDefault();

      string Humidity = (string)Document.Descendants("humidity.value").FirstOrDefault();

      string WindSpeed = (string)Document.Descendants("timezone").FirstOrDefault();

      string Country = (string)Document.Descendants("country").FirstOrDefault();


      temp.Text = Temperature;

      txtHumidty.Text = Humidity;

      txtWind.Text = WindSpeed;

      cityDisplay.Text = city;
 }
```

Comment: Debug code yourself put break point in code (F9) and then step through code (F11) and hover over variables with mouse to see values.

Comment: @jdweng it says that they are null but the xml api is not null

Comment: Need to see sample of xml.  I suspect there is a namespace.  See my answer from this morning on how to handle the namespace : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244064/display-field-from-xml-response-data-using-c-sharp-console/62244965#62244965

Comment: @jdweng can I send you the example of the xml ?

Comment: Update your answer using edit and post beginning of xml which will contain the namespace.

Comment: @jdweng it didn't let me paste the file tags so I added one of the examples like this

Comment: I need to see the xml.  When you press edit the is a box  with <>.   Press and insert xml into view.

Comment: @jdweng Here is the xml file

Comment: The namespace is at the beginning of the file and all you posted was the current element.  I need to see the beginning of the file with the opening tag.

Comment: @jdweng unfortunately that is all from this xml file . I will probably try with JSON type .

Comment: Then issue is the xml is not well formed.  A well formed xml has only one root tag.  Your xml has an array of tags at the root.  So you need to handle the array.  Try following :             XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("URL", settings);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);